# how to check file exists and get file size by substring?

Tags: perl, file, filesize, file-extension

I have a directory will create every day file  like '2018-08-14-9-22-4',
the file name created is by yyyy-mm-dd-h-m-s, 
how to check file is exists by substring like '2018-08-14' ?
and get the file full name  and file size ?

```
my $file =  "$yy-$mm-$dd-$hh-$mm-$ss";
my $path = '/home/httpd/doc/$user/$year/[every day file]'
```

Comment: You appear to have attempted to add the solution to your question. Please don't do that. I have rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way would be to use the pattern matching in [`glob`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html), and then use [`stat`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) on the file.

```
for my $name ( glob('2018-08-14-*') ) { 
    my $size = ( stat($name) )[7];
    say "name is '$name', size is $size bytes";
}
```

or better yet... use [`File::stat`](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/stat.html)

```
use File::stat;

for my $name ( glob('2018-08-14-*') ) { 
    my $size = stat($name)->size;
    say "name is '$name', size is $size bytes";
}
```

I answered a similar question on [r/perl](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/8nxgox/globbing_in_different_directory/dzzj7wq/) that's worth reading if you interested in the different ways to do what you want

**UPDATE**

If you have created a filename variable, and you want to check if it exists, just use the [file test operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

```
my $file =  "$yy-$mm-$dd-$hh-$mm-$ss";
my $path = "/home/httpd/doc/$user/$year/";

if (-e $path) { say "$path exists" }
if (-d $path) { say "$path is a dir" }
if (-w $path) { say "$path is a writeable" }

if (-e "$path/$file" && -r "$path/$file" ) {
    say "$path/$file exists and is readable"
}
```

Comment: but how to get the file name from my $path ??

Comment: @georgetovrea - Use `File::Spec` if you want individual components of it or to normalize it. (Or `File::Basename` or `Cwd` or several other modules depending on what you want to do)

Comment: Need `$path` there, and might as well take care of possible spaces in names with either of these: `glob qq{"$path/2018-08-14*"};` or `glob "\Q$path/...\E"` or `use File::Glob ':bsd_glob'; my @files = glob "$path/2018-08-14*";`

Comment: Note that `$path/*` allows an injection bug, and I am not sure whether `bsd_glob` or double quoting prevent it.  This is the main reason for the escape sequence, `\Q...\E`, which also escapes spaces so it solves that problem as well.

Comment: @zdim, You need quotemeta with `bsd_glob` too. Space isn't the only special character!

Comment: @ikegami Ah, right, thank you.  I'll leave it now since it's been noted.  Sometimes I wish I could edit comments.

Comment: @Joshua , but how to check the file (2018-08-14-*) is exists or not  first?

Comment: @georgetovrea You want to check if _any_ files match `2018-08-14-*` first? You could assign the result of glob to an array first. `my @files = glob('2018-08-14-*'); if (@files) { # files exist }`. However, it's worth mentioning that in my answer above, it will only enter the `for` loop if files exist. If `glob` returned nothing, the loop would not run.

Comment: @georgetovrea If you have created a filename string and you want to check if it exists first, just use the [file test operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html). `my $file =  "$yy-$mm-$dd-$hh-$mm-$ss"; my $path = "/home/httpd/doc/$user/$year/$file"; if (-e $path) { print "$path exists" }`

Comment: Again: this won't work.  Their file is in `$path` directory while your `glob` seeks the bare filename (without the path).

Answer (score 2):

Your path should be double-quoted, if it contains variables. If the path is single-quoted, `$file` and `$year` won't get interpolated

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;

my ($user,$year) = @ARGV;
my $check = '2018-08-14';

opendir my $dir_handle, "/home/httpd/doc/$user/$year/";

# use File::Basename to get the filename from each file in the dir
# use regex to check if each filename starts with the string to check for
while (readdir $dir_handle) {
    my $name = basename($_);
    if ($name =~ /^$check/) {
        say "$name found. size: ". -s $dir.$name;
    }
}
```

Comment: ,but now my problem I don't know the filename ($yy-$mm-$dd-$hh-$mm-$ss) , only I can get the file name is start with $yy-$mm-$dd , but I don't know $hh-$mm-$ss ??

Comment: Fair enough. Your original question was a bit vague, but in retrospect I guess you did say that. The answer is edited to extract the filename for each file in the dir, and check for your date string with regex.

Comment: The `readdir` returns bare filename, without the path; so there is no need for `basename`. But it does return the filename given to it (`$_`), so this will still work.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, thanks. `File::Basename` is unnecessary because `readdir` gives you the basenames. I'll leave it in to avoid confusion by editing it though.