# If file exists with wildcard?

Tags: perl, file-exists

I need to verify if a file exists, but the file name changes. At least the last part of the file name does due to appending time (hh-mm-ss).

So basically, I need to see if file yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss exists irrespective of what the  hh-mm-ss is.
I'm trying to do a wildcard search but it doesn't find the file.
For example, I want to check if the file `/home/httpd/doc/$user/$year/2018-08-20-*` exists.

Is it possible to use `*` for the filename variable? Or an other better way?

I'm trying to check if a file exists, but with a wildcard.  Here is my code:

```
opendir(DIR, "/home/httpd/doc/$user/2018") || die "Unable to open log/location";
while(<>){
    if($_ =~ /\/2018-08-20-\d+-\d+-\d+/) {
        print "file exists\n";
      }
 }
```

Comment: The `while (<>)` that you try is a little special: The `<>` reads lines from files which are submitted to the program at start.  So if you say `script.pl file1 file2` then `while (<>)` in the progam `script.pl` will read _lines_ from `file1` and `file2`, one after another.  Not what you want here. (Once you `opendir` then you can do as mob's answer shows.)

Comment: (A bit more precisely, `<>` opens files which names are in `@ARGV` and reads them)

Comment: Hi @georgetovrea I do believe you have already asked this question, and I think it has been answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832909/how-to-check-file-exists-and-get-file-size-by-substring/

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are trying to use the `opendir`-`readdir` pattern, which would look like

```
opendir(DIR, "/home/httpd/doc/$user/2018") || die "Unable to open log/location";
foreach my $file (readdir DIR) {
    if ($file =~ /\/2018-08-20-\d+-\d+-\d+/) {
        print "file exists\n";
    }
}
closedir DIR;
```

but a more concise way (with more edge cases but would probably work in your case) would be to use `glob`

```
if (glob("/home/httpd/doc/$user/2018/2018-08-20-*")) {
    print "file exists\n";
}
```